# URL rewrite using Regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a software tool to create some 301 Redirects Rules for my Joomla site. Example:
From

```
http://myhost/directory/category/article
```

to

```
http://myhost/directory/main-category/category/article
```

In practice I add the "main-category" to the URL. By specifying the full URL, redirect happens correctly. For example:

```
Source URL: ^/temp/clustering/cluster-example
Destination URL: http://localhost/temp/main-category/clustering/cluster-example
```

However I'd like to use Regular expressions to avoid creating a Redirect for every page. I'd need something like:

```
Source URL: ^/temp/clustering/*
Destination URL: http://localhost/temp/main-category/clustering/???????
```

I need a regular expression instead of "??????" which places the last element of the path there (In my case it's "cluster-example".
As far as I know, this engine uses [MySQL implementation of regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) 
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this rule as **very first rule** in your `/temp/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /temp/

RewriteRule ^(clustering/.+)$ main-category/$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```